# How to show a textbox and dropdown when a radiobutton when is checked using jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Hi all i have some radio buttons and text boxes corresponding to each radio button..what i want to do is when an radio button is checked show the corresponding textbox from the following format..

```
        @foreach(var item in Viewbag.Ids)
        {
         <div class="group">
          <label class="label">
           @Html.RadioButton("Rdbtn",new{value=@item.value})
          </label>
            <div class="control">
                  <input type="text"  />
            <div>
        </div>
```

in another case

```
       <div>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.IsFlat)
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.IsFree)
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.IsTax)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Products)
       </div>
```

what am i doing for the above only one of the radio button has to be checked when one is checked the other should be unchecked i am doing it like this

```
   $('input[type=radio]').change( function(){
    if(this.checked)
        {
                  $(this).closest('div').find('input[type=radio]').not(this).attr('checked',false)
        }
     });
```

this is working fine and i want to dsiplay the  dropdwon when an "  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.IsTax)" is checked how can i do this and i have to get the radio button checked in edit mode if it is checked can any one help me in doing this

Comment: I could write this real quick for you but...  "m.IsFlat" , "m.IsFree" -these sound like bool's , are you sure you have this thought out, you don't want check boxes for bools? then write script for if one checkbox checked?   Radio buttons are all supposed to be bound to one value.

Comment: @ScottSelby those are bool values and those are radio buttons that is the requirement here...can you provide me sol with in both ways it will be helpfull for for me ..

Answer (score 0):

For your first question

change razor code to add a class

```
 @Html.RadioButton("Rdbtn",new{ .value = @item.value , .class = "radio1"})
```

then change jquery to:

```
$('.radio1').change( function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
       $(this).closest('input').show();
  }
```

second question

add a class in each of these radio's

```
  @Html.RadioButton("Rdbtn",new{value=@item.value, new { .class = "radio2"})
```

then jquery

```
$('.radio2').change(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); //im not too sure you need this
  $('.radio2').attr('checked', false);
  $(this).attr('checked', true);    
});
```

Like I said in my comment , this answer to the second question I highly reccommend you don't do , and am not even sure it will actually work.  The script will work on client side, it will do what you want , but server side it will probably throw errors trying to bind radio buttons to bools the way to did .  AGAIN , this answer is because you asked for it - IT IS NOT the right way to do it.